# JMC Java Flight Recorder not enabled

Tags: eclipse, jmc, jfr

I am using spring tool suite with the java mission control plugin to start an app which I would like to monitor using the JFR. I added `-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder` to the `SpringToolSuite4.ini` and additionally set JAVA_OPTS with those two flags (both of which is not necessary if I understand it correctly) and `-XX:+FlightRecorder` in Run configurations > Arguments > VM arguments of the application to be monitored. When adding both flags as well to the run configuration the application cannot be started with the openJdk.

After starting the application in the JVM Browser when selecting the Flight Recorder I get the following exception.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Flight Recorder features are not enabled. To enable this you need to use a Java 7u4 or later JVM started with -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder.
    at com.oracle.jmc.flightrecorder.controlpanel.ui.FlightRecorderProvider.refresh(FlightRecorderProvider.java:105)
    at com.oracle.jmc.browser.views.JVMBrowserView$1.run(JVMBrowserView.java:98)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: com.oracle.jmc.rjmx.services.jfr.FlightRecorderException: Flight Recorder features are not enabled. To enable this you need to use a Java 7u4 or later JVM started with -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder.
    at com.oracle.jmc.flightrecorder.controlpanel.ui.FlightRecorderProvider.getService(FlightRecorderProvider.java:161)
    at com.oracle.jmc.flightrecorder.controlpanel.ui.FlightRecorderProvider.refreshRecordings(FlightRecorderProvider.java:117)
    at com.oracle.jmc.flightrecorder.controlpanel.ui.FlightRecorderProvider.refresh(FlightRecorderProvider.java:94)
    ... 7 more
```

I tried it with the following java versions.

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.2" 2018-10-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.2+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.2+7, mixed mode)
```

or with the JDK from oracle

```
$ java -version
java version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS, mixed mode)
```

For none of the above mentioned JDK's there is a jmc.exe which was there with java 8. Is that part of the plugin?

How can I get this running?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, Java 11 requires JMC 7 to be able to start and view recordings.
JMC 7 EA builds are expected to appear here soon - https://jdk.java.net/jmc/

In the meantime you can build JMC yourself, see http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jmc/jmc7/ (or github, not exactly sure which version it is synced to - https://github.com/JDKMissionControl/jmc) and the README on how to build.

You can start recordings using JVM command line flags, and using jcmd, and parse the recordings using https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.jfr/jdk/jfr/consumer/package-summary.html

Comment: Thanks. Tried to build but the jetty doesn't start due to `java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind`. There are no servers running - closed all other apps. Where can I configure the port? The last link in your answer (...package-summary.html) doesn't exist.

Comment: Don't know about the license, but you could check out Azul's binaries https://www.azul.com/products/zulu-mission-control/ meanwhile. They support the latest file format etc.

Comment: For the port: add ```<connector>
       <port>9999</port>
     </connector>``` to the configuration for the jetty-maven-plugin in `releng/third-party/pom.xml`, then change the port from 8080 to 9999 in the `releng/platform-definitions/platfoprm-definition-xyz.target`files (not 100% which is used)